# VBA String concatenation

Tags: vba, string

Is there any Java-like solution for concatenatin strings in VBA?

I want to use a MsgBox in a way like this:

```
...
Set UT = Workbooks(dropdownValue).Worksheets(1)
With UT
       UT_rows = .Cells(3, 15).End(xlDown).Row
End With
MsgBox "Rows of the file: " + UT_rows
```

But when I do that, my code hangs up at this point. (incompatible Types)

Comment: The code is fine. I believe the message box appears but gets overlapped by other (top-level?) windows.  
Otherwise please provide more details about how this code is called and what is `variable`.

Comment: "variable" is just a value, which was read out from an Excel (2003) cell

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should always use `&` when concatenating;

```
MsgBox "Rows of the file: " & UT_rows
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the point :) Coming from java I've never thought about this...thanks a lot